# Exotic logic gate

Tags: digital-logic

I have a negation operation and two types of "logic gates" with following outputs (A, B are inputs):

"gate" 1:

```
A | B | OUT
x   0    1
0   x    1
0   0    1
0   1    x (no output)
1   0    x (no output)
x   x    x (no output)
1   1    0
x   1    0
1   x    0
```

"gate" 2:

```
A | B | OUT
x   0    0
0   x    1
0   0    x (no output)
0   1    1
1   0    0
1   1    x (no output)
x   1    1
1   x    0
x   x    x (no output)
```

I can join these two "gates" to form the third one:

```
A | B | OUT
x   0    x (no output)
0   x    1
0   0    1
0   1    1
1   0    0
1   1    0
x   1    x (no output)
1   x    0
x   x    x (no output)
```

Is it possible to use these (half gates or joined gates) to build regular binary logic NOR or NAND gates, given that it is possible to additionally negate any input and/or output?.

Negation op is:

```
A | OUT
x    x (no output)
0    1
1    0
```

## The problem

The main difficulty is to make the "joined gate" inputs (0,1) and (1,0):

```
A | B | OUT
0   1    1
1   0    0
```

to always output 1 or 0 like:

```
A | B | OUT
0   1    0
1   0    0
```

This is the only change needed to get the NOR gate. The question is how to do it with these "gates", if it's possible at all.

Comment: Your "joined gate" is NOT(A) (the B input is irrelevant to the output) so not helpful at all given that you stated already have negation for free.  By _no output_ do you mean _don't care_ or do you intend something like _high impedance_ (like in a multiplexor arm?)

Comment: The question is impossible to answer in its present form because you've introduced gates that have three output states, but have not defined their behavior for all three states on their inputs (other than to say that NOT(x) = x).

Comment: @DaveTweed: just fixed that

Comment: If the question is if these are equivalent to "regular binary logic NOR or NAND gates", which also don't specify behavior for "x" inputs, then how is the behavior of these gates when they have "x" inputs relevant at all?

Comment: @WanderingLogic: no output means something like high impedance - it simply stops propagating the signal

Comment: @PhilFrost: see it like this: 0 means negative current flow, 1 means positive current flow, x means no current at all. Signal propagates with current flow, there's not propagation for x outputs, but it's possible to join different gates so one of the gates will set the otherwise unset x output. I think the -1, 0 and 1 are better values for these gates... but still, they're not regular ternary gates.

Comment: @PiotrSzturmaj How you represent *x* electrically is irrelevant. What does a NAND or NOR gate do when an input is *x*? There is no answer, because the behavior of a NAND or NOR gate is only defined if the inputs are *true* or *false*. So, what your gates do when any input is *x* is also irrelevant: we can say the behavior is *undefined*, just like a NAND or NOR gate.

Comment: Given that the output of the "join" function is exactly "NOT A" as you have defined NOT, there doesn't seem to be much hope. It would remain to be seen whether combining "gate1", "gate2" and "join" in other combinations would produce anything useful. What is the context/motivation for this question? Without that, it will have to be closed as "not constructive" or "too localized".

Comment: @PhilFrost: no, here the behaviour is always defined. See the truth tables (I added x input cases). The first gate is like this: current will flow in the opposite direction to current flowing in A, in B or in both A and B, but when current in A  flows in opposite direction to B, both currents cancel each other and the output is x (no output). The 2nd gate is similar, but it outputs current only if current direction in A is in opposite to B. When it flows in the same direction in A and B then it is cancelled, and there's no output.

Comment: @DaveTweed: not exactly, you can negate the 1st gate before joining it with the 2nd. Also please take into account the x inputs. I'm trying to build the NOR/NAND gate with the use of inductively coupled coils. This is my personal interest and research :) I'm trying to prove (or disprove) that it's possible to build asynchronous logic circuits in this way. EDIT: also, I know it's possible with the use of diodes, but I'd like to see if it's possible without them.

Comment: @PiotrSzturmaj is it allowed to have constant inputs into the logic? That is, can we make a new unary gate composed of one of these gates where one input is some constant value?

Comment: @PhilFrost: no, the inputs and outputs are transient. This is different that regular voltage-level logic. Here the input or output means momentary current flow in either direction.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to build the NOR/NAND gate with the use of inductively coupled coils. This is my personal interest and research :) I'm trying to prove (or disprove) that it's possible to build asynchronous logic circuits in this way.

Why didn't you ask that in the first place? It would have saved a lot of time.

Yes, it is possible to build logic with transformers. Have you ever heard of "[rope memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_rope_memory)"? It's a form of read-only memory built entirely from wires and ferrite toroids. It was used, for example, to store the instructions in the Apollo guidance computers.

The point is, a ROM (any ROM, no matter what the technology) is essentially a huge matrix of AND and OR gates, so it meets your basic functional requirement. However, it depends on exactly what you mean by "asynchronous" in this context. Transformers do not couple energy from DC signals, and so magnetic logic of this type is always driven by pulses, not DC currents.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I'm not trying to build ROM but simple AND/OR/XOR gates (which can be build from NOR or NAND). For asynchronous circuit, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_circuit - it basically means circuit without a clock. Yes, I know it must be driven by pulses.

Comment: You can make a ROM as small as you like. A ROM with two inputs and one output is called a "gate".

Comment: This is interesting, could you clarify it a bit? Is it possible to build an adder with those "gates"?

Comment: I'm hardly an expert. But I think if you understand in detail how the address decoding in rope memory works, you'll gain a lot of insight into the concepts behind magnetic logic in general. You have to dig for it, but the information is out there.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this question correctly, you're dealing with trinary logic, where you have three states 0, 1, and x. You have two trinary gates: g1 and g2. (Note that the truth table for g2 is in a different order than g1) You want to create NAND and NOR gates out of these gates. I assume that you only care about 0 and 1 inputs to the NAND and NOR gates and don't care what they output for an x input.

I made a Python program to brute-force try gate combinations and found ways to generate NAND and NOR. For NAND, use g1(g1(1, g1), g1(g1, g1)). For NOR, use g2(g1(g1, g1), g2(1, g1)). [The "leaf" gates take A and B as inputs.]

To understand the NAND logic, note that g1 in effect is a "NOT majority" gate. It checks if there are more 0 or 1 inputs and outputs 1 for majority 0, 0 for majority 1, and x for tie.

So g1(g1, g1) applies "NOT majority", doubles, and applies "NOT majority" again, which is just the "majority" function. Meanwhile, g1(1, g1) does "NOT majority", provides another 1, and does "NOT majority" again, yielding x if there is a majority of 1 inputs and 0 otherwise. Finally, applying g1 to these two sub-results yields 0 if there is a majority of 1 inputs and 1 otherwise, which is the desired NAND logic.

Answer (score 0):

**HUL logic**

I think your basic idea is faulted because in your system the OUTPUT of one gate cannot connect as (a defined) INPUT to another. A 'floating' input cannot be determined. Binary logic works because there are TWO defined (and related) states. Your system has THREE states (Trinary logic). but doesn't define the third state in terms of the other two. Instead of using a state that cannot be tested for (no output) why not give it a value that is different to '1' (high) and '0' (low) but related to them. I would suggest something like

HIGH (a positive voltage/current), LOW (about zero voltage/current) and UNDER (a negative voltage/current)

It would then be relatively easy to detect each (voltage or current) state (H,U,L) and construct a 'gate' according to some logic with the inputs or outputs either positive, 0 or negative.

[image]